# image in a div isn't spanning the entire width of the page

Tags: html, css

so im working on a project for work. the long black container on the bottom does not span the entire width of the page. It stops a few pixels short on either side. Here is my code:

```
   http://74.117.156.152/~pr0digy/
```

```
    <header class="mainHeader">
        <img src="images/uslegalbox.png" alt="usls box" >
    </header>

    <div class="textBox">

            <article class="capexText">
                <h2>Capital</h2><br />
                <h2>Expenditures</h2>
            </article>          

        <div class="buttonsBox">
            <nav><ul>
                <li><a href="#" >New CapEx</li>
                <li><a href="#" >Check Status</li>  
            </ul></nav>
        </div>

    </div>
```

And the CSS to go along with it:

```
body {
        background: url('images/bg.jpg');
        background-size: 100%;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        color: #000305;
        font-size: 87.5%; /* Base font size is 14px */
        font-family: Arial; 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
        line-height: 1.2;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;    
}

.mainHeader {
        width: 30%
        height: auto;
        margin: 2% 0 0 -1%;
}

.mainHeader img {
        width: 35%;
        height: auto;
}

.textBox {
        margin-top: 10%;
        height: 275px;
        background-image: url('images/buttonsbox.png');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;


}
```

I'm sure im just missing something simple, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added 
    `margin:0;
    padding:0;`
to the body style it will reset the default margin and padding to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a reset stylesheet like [Eric Meyers](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) so set all elements styles to a default. (remove body/html padding etc)